# How can I run postgres with data dir on /tmp?

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, tmpfs

I'm running automated integration tests using data stored in a postgres database. I need to start every test run with the same database contents. Instead of always clearing the database and importing a dump, I want to copy the database to /tmp and run it from there. If it works, it is easier and faster. This is what I did:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/postgres/data
chown -R postgres:postgres /tmp/postgres
rsync -vacHAX /var/lib/postgres/data/ /tmp/postgres/data/
```

and adapted the `postgresql.service` file to the new location (including `systemctl daemon-reload`).

But if I try to start postgres with this setup, it fails and `systemctl status postgresql.service` says

> "/tmp/postgres/data" is missing or empty.

which is just not true.

I double-checked that the postgres user owns and has access to /tmp/pgsql/data/. Free space on /tmp is also sufficient (over 2 times the database size).

I've tried a different location and it worked. So my changes in the `postgresql.service` file are sufficient to use a non-default locattion. **It only fails on /tmp.**

What am I missing ?

Comment: Is your problem [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-postgresql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04)?

Comment: Not an answer, but: For automated tests, consider using a different database name (what you put as `dbname` in the connection string, and see with `\c` in `psql`) as test database. Copy it initially from your main database, change the connection string in your automated tests, and do each test inside a transaction; rollback after test is finished. Then every test will execute against a defined database state. No need to copy the database files on the filesystem to somewhere else.

Comment: @harrymc no. As I wrote, I can use another location, it only fails on /tmp.

Comment: @dirkt not possible in my case, the software in test uses postgres-specific features, and I would need to export the existing postgres data in a format the other database understands

Comment: Did you check if the permissions are identical on the source/target directories?

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear: A single postgres server allows several databases. If you don't specify a database name on connect, you connect to `postgres` database. Assuming you did that, `CREATE DATABASE testdb TEMPLATE postgres` copies the complete default database over to a new database named `testdb`, **including** all postgres-specific features. You only ever have a single database server running.

Comment: @dirkt OK, this is a feasible workaround for now. Thanx.

Comment: @harrymc yes, of course. I double-checked. And because I used rsync, it would have been very strange if the permissions would have been different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

systemd services can have a private `/tmp` directory for security reasons.
From [systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html):

> PrivateTmp=
>
> Takes a boolean argument. If true, sets up a new file system namespace for the executed processes and mounts private /tmp/ and
> /var/tmp/ directories inside it that are not shared by processes
> outside of the namespace

When you say it's not true that `/tmp/postgres/data` is empty or non-existing, that's from the point of view of your shell, not the point of view of the postgres service if `PrivateTmp=true`.

Comment: I learned something new. And by setting it to false, it worked. thanks.